# $(this).height() is zero on mobile while on desktop it has its intended height

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, mobile

I've ran into a problem that the ($this) object's height is 0 on mobile while it has the height on desktop
This problem only occurs on the first load of the site. After I reload it or i access the site via url, the object has the intended height!

Here's the code:

```
var maxLaenge = 0;
var minHoehe = 0;
$(this).find(".img").each(function() {
    var imgLaenge = $(this).width();
    if (imgLaenge > maxLaenge) {
        maxLaenge = imgLaenge;
        minHoehe = $(this).height();
        console.log($(this));
    }
});
```

Comment: I found out that the $(this) object has the height of 0 on mobile, while on desktop it has its intended size.

Comment: What does the first `$(this)` refer to? And you're searching for `.img`, so objects with the class `img`? Or do you want all the images?

Comment: the first $(this) represents the actual DOM element, in this case it is the element which is ran through the loop. and Yes i only want the height of the images with the class img

Comment: Then the script is probably ran before all the images are loaded. The images are cached on the first download and a refresh serves them immediately.

Comment: i've realised that the $(document).ready function fires too early.
i've fixed it with wrapping the code with $(window).on("load", function() {}
thank you for your help!